# VB.net MySQL Update all items in the listview

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

How do i update items in the ListView at the same time in my database? I have this code but i don't know what's wrong, It only updates the first row in the Listview. I want to update all the items that is shown in the listview

```
 For Each row As ListViewItem In ListView3.Items
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = "update pawn set status = 'Redeemed' where pawn_id = '" & ListView3.Items(0).Text & "'"
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader


            con.Close()

        Next
```

Comment: SideNote:  [How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always sending 0th  element of listview in parameter.

Here is error:

```
cmd.CommandText = "update pawn set status = 'Redeemed' where pawn_id = '" & ListView3.Items(0).Text & "'"
```

There should be:

```
cmd.CommandText = "update pawn set status = 'Redeemed' where pawn_id = '" & row.Text & "'"
```

If You always send `ListView3.Items(0).Text` in WHERE statement - it always updates same row.